# Constraint on table enable for part of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a database and there are two tables Employees and Cards. There is a primary key EmplID in Employees table which is a foreign key in Cards table. The new feature requires to add records (temporary cards) into Cards table with fake (randomly generated) EmplID which is not exists in Employees table. I need some replacement for the foreign key in Cards table, which will work for part of records in the table.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I don't really follow what you want to do.

Comment: I have an employee EmplName: "John Doe", EmplID: 12345 in the Employees table. There is a record with same EmplID in Cards table. Both records in two tables linked with the constraint. I want to have a possibility to insert into Cards another record with fake EmplID, which is not exists in  Employees table, but keep a linkage between two tables for " John Doe"

Comment: No - that is not possible. And I suggest you (or whoever came up with this "requirement") think long and hard about the actual goal. Your schema (and presumably suppporting code) are designed with this relationship. Trying to subvert that now will cause all sorts of problems with your system. If you must do something like this, then I suggest another table - perhaps called FakeCards - and use a union of the 2 tables when you need to query card information.

Comment: Why not add a fake record to the Employee table to match the fake record in the Cards table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely agree with SMor that doing this is probably a very bad idea. You should rethink your requirements and what you're trying to accomplish.

The simplest solution is just adding a record to the Employee table with the fake ID, so that the constraint is maintained.

That being said, is it possible?  Yes, ... kind of, ... sort of.

First, you need to be able to distinguish between the fake records that don't need the constraint, and the real ones that do.  In my example, I've added a boolean flag, `IsFake`, but your criterion might be different.

Then create a computed column that holds the `EmpID` if it's a real record, and `NULL` if it is fake, and set up the foreign key constraint against that column.  Note, in order to force a foreign key constraint on a computed column, it must be **persisted**.

```
create table Emp ( EmpID int not null primary key identity(1,1), 
                   EmpName nvarchar(60) )

create table Crd ( CrdID int not null primary key identity(1,1),
                   IsFake bit not null,
                   MaybeEmpID int,
                   CrdVal nvarchar(60),

                   EmpID as 
                     case when IsFake=1 then NULL else MaybeEMPID end 
                     persisted 
                     foreign key references Emp(EmpID)
                   )

-- Create some real records
declare @ID int

insert into Emp ( EmpName ) values ( 'Fred' )
set @ID = scope_identity()
insert into Crd ( IsFake, MaybeEmpID, CrdVal ) values ( 0, @ID, 'King' )
insert into Crd ( IsFake, MaybeEmpID, CrdVal ) values ( 0, @ID, 'Jack' )

insert into Emp ( EmpName ) values ( 'Mary' )
set @ID = scope_identity()
insert into Crd ( IsFake, MaybeEmpID, CrdVal ) values ( 0, @ID, 'Queen' )
insert into Crd ( IsFake, MaybeEmpID, CrdVal ) values ( 0, @ID, 'Ace'   )

-- Create some fake records
insert into Crd ( IsFake, MaybeEmpID, CrdVal ) values ( 1, 9876789, 'Five'  )
insert into Crd ( IsFake, MaybeEmpID, CrdVal ) values ( 1, 9876789, 'Three' )
insert into Crd ( IsFake, MaybeEmpID, CrdVal ) values ( 1, 7474747, 'Seven' )

select * from Emp

select * from Crd

select * from Emp,Crd where Emp.EmpID = Crd.EmpID
```